# Saving project with data source path as relative in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, file-path

Is there an option in QGIS to save the project with the data source being a relative path?

I don't see the option here. QGIS Wroclaw1.7.3[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Goto:

1. **Settings**
2. **Project Properties..**
3. Now check the **general tab**

you should see **save paths** and besides **relativ** ( I believe its even standard since vers. 1.73, before 1.73 the default was absolut)

Kurt

ps. just take at look at the screenshot made by manning above ;-)

pps: your screenshot is from settings --> options , thats the wrong way

Comment: It does seem like Relative is now the default (hooray!) and previously it was Absolue.

Answer (score 13):

Yes.  In the `Settings` > `Project Properties` > `General` tab, there is an option to use Absolute or Relative path.

[image]

Comment: Please check for the screenshot above. I dont see this option in QGIS Wroclaw 1.7.3

Comment: It is definitely available also in qgis 1.7.3

Comment: me too (I agree with GM)

Comment: Options != Project Properties

Comment: Update: Since QGIS 2.0, the Project properties have moved from the Settings to the File menu.

Answer (score 10):

In version 2.18, the relative path was an option but didn't actually work.
**Project ➜  Project Properties ➜ General ➜ General settings ➜ Save paths.**

[image]

However, it does work in 3.2:
**Project ➜  Properties ➜ General ➜ General settings ➜ Save paths.**
[image]

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS 3.10 you can open the Projects tab and click on Properties, then click on the General tab. A new window will show up as portrayed in the screen capture below. The selection is highlighted in yellow and circled.[image: Saving relative pathways]