# Sending compressed folder with shapefiles and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, compression

When I compress my QGIS file with the folder containing all my shapefiles, how can I maintain the paths?

For example, I made a map on QGIS using a large amount of shapefiles. Once done, I save my QGIS file to 
C:\Users\Workcomputer\Desktop\New_folder

From there I compress the shapefiles and the QGIS file located in \New_folder and send the newly made .zip file to myself by email or dropbox.

However, when I download and uncompress the .zip on a different computer, the QGIS file is empty, and I have to re-path all the shapefiles, because they are now located in

C:\Users\Homecomputer\Desktop\New_folder

instead of

C:\Users\Workcomputer\Desktop\New_folder

Is there anyway to short-cut having to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Settings > Project Properties > General tab, you will find an option to use either Absolute or Relative paths. Selecting relative paths should sort out your issue. You may want to look at this answer: [How to save project with data source path as relative in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/how-to-save-project-with-data-source-path-as-relative-in-qgis)