# want to burn my qgis project on cd_problem with opening pictures and changing directory

Tags: qgis, photos

I have created a QGIS project and want to burn it on CD. For a better demonstration I have linked pictures to every point in my point-shapefiles. The problem that I am facing is, that when I open the project on a different computer via CD, everything is shown but not the pictures when I use the identify tool, as the linkage to my c-system is no longer available. How can I change the directory of my photo linkage so that it uses the folder with the pictures that is provided on the CD but no longer on the c-system. 
My whole project is in one main folder that already contains the picture folder. I will burn the whole folder on the CD. Only the linkage with the pictures does not work. The rest opens up just fine. Is there any solution for that problem?

Comment: Have you considered this suggestion https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/saving-project-with-data-source-path-as-relative-in-qgis/20366 ?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure, even though you copied the pictures folder to your project folder, that the images within your project are actually pointing to that new location and not still to the original place on your "c-system"? (i.e. double check they have been re-linked ... this simple issue gets me sometimes).

Comment: Yes, I think I did that. Just for you to have an idea how my folder structures looks like:

Comment: One main folder with several subfolders. one subfolder is the q-gis project, one subfolder is the picturefolder. both are on my c-system. everthing in the qgis-folder works because i have enable the relative pathway so that i can open it on any computer. every point-shape point has a link to the picture inside the picture-subfolder and that is still linked to the c-folder. there i can not add anywhere the relative linkage. does ist help to put a folder inside the qgisfolder with the pictures?

Comment: Why do you want to burn it to CD?  Are you trying to share the data with someone else?

Comment: Yes, I have to hand it in as a university report. Thats why it has to go on CD.