# Problems with shared projects that include files in OneDrive

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, server, storage, onedrive

I used to share QGIS projects with colleagues by storing our files in a server, which everyone would have access to. Recently we started using OneDrive and this has become a problem with the projects that we all share, because if we store the files in a OneDrive and then the rest synchronise their folders, we will still have different paths. e.g.

We store the folder in my OneDrive

```
C:\Users\XXX My username XXX\OneDrive - XX Company Name XX\Projects\Working\XXX.qgz
```

Even if my colleagues synchronise the file in their local drives, they will have something like

```
C:\Users\XXX Their username XXX\XX Company Name XX\XX My name XX - XX Project Folder XX\XXX.qgz
```

This means QGIS will not be able to find the files, and they will not be able to use the project.

My question is, does anyone know how to use shared projects with others with files stored in OneDrive (or similar storage platforms)? Is there anything I can do in QGIS to address this issue? Or is the only solution to go back and store files in the server?

Comment: use relative paths and resave the .qgz > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/saving-project-with-data-source-path-as-relative-in-qgis