# QField and Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, qfield

I use QField for my field recording with photo documentation. The synchronization takes place via USB from tablet to PC, everything works without problems.
With my recording and the atlas function, I have created a print layout that reproduces the desired attributes such as map section, title, legend without any problems. Now I would like to integrate the photos I took into the atlas function, unfortunately no image appears, but a red X in the image box. I've been looking for the mistake for days. What am I doing wrong or is it not possible to reproduce the picture?

---

I make a picture box and then I go to item properties. I switch from svg image to raster image. I choose field type: string, photo.
Then I get a red x in the box.

Comment: You should at least, show us how you are trying to get your picture path dynamically ?

Comment: You need to explain how you did try to display your picture like how you set up your "image box", did you use an expression in relation to your atlas setting ? you need to show your whole setting

Comment: are you using relative paths in QGIS? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/saving-project-with-data-source-path-as-relative-in-qgis

Comment: yes i use relative paths in qgis

Answer (score 1):

You can use project variable `@project_path`. You will be able to concatenate that variable with a dynamic field value using expression Manager.

If the filename is stored as attribute, the full path syntax should be similar to :

```
@project_folder || '/' || [% "filename" %]
```

I will give you the advice to create first a Text box object to be able to visualize the result and check if the generated path is correct. When it is, just switch to Image object !

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I created a text box and used it variably. the path changes dynamically with the map section. when I switch to the picture box, the picture is not visible and the red x appears.
do I have a wrong setting?

Comment: what is the generated path ? and does it seems correct ? Copy / paste it by editing your original  post (Question). By the way, this is note a forum, please have a look on https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour to understand how it works

Comment: my memory path for the Qfield project is 'DCIM / schaden_' || format_date (now (), 'yyyyMMdddhhmmsszzz') || '.jpg'