# Why do I keep having to restore layer path names in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-path

Quite often I am having to restore the layer path names for many of my QGIS projects. The projects and the relevant shapefiles are all stored in a shared network that allows my colleagues to use and edit the projects and shapefiles. All computers with access to the shared network are running QGIS 3.10. I can see no commonalities between the file types, or the folders they are in that could cause this.

Comment: Are you all using the same directory letter or path for the network share?

Comment: You may try to switch to saving absolute path and edit the project in a text editor so the path doesn't use drive letter but "the real" path (so going from like  "L:\GIS_FOLDER\DATA... "to something like "\\mydomain.xxx\....\GIS_FOLDER\DATA..."), if  @bugmenot123 is right about the drive path issue it may solve the problem

Comment: @bugmenot123 No, but I'm not sure how to change this. When I access the shared network called "Norbury Park Ltd" the path is as follows "C:\Users\George.shortman\Norbury Park Ltd\Woodland - Documents\QGis\Projects", but when someone else accesses the shared network it will have their name instead of "George.shortman".

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually caused by the project referencing its layers with absolute paths, including the drive letter and path components like the user name. You probably solve the issue by saving the QGIS project with relative paths inside, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354160/51035.