# Exporting project to a GeoPackage

Tags: export, geopackage

I have a QGIS project that includes various types of files: multiline string, multipolygon, point data, and geotiffs of various multispectral outputs with unique symbologies within a 5-level folder structure.

Firstly, I want to share this project with colleagues, and I can't seem to work out how best to export it.

I can't export the multispectral geotiff outputs. I've tried exporting the overarching folder as a .qlr, but I can't import it to the GeoPackage database as it's not a raster layer. I would like to retain the spectral information for my colleagues.

I'm using 3.28.14-Firenze

Answer (score 1):

Put all the data into a single directory organized as you see fit.  Save a copy of the QGIS file into that same directory.  Ensure the data in your QGIS project map file paths to the data located in that directory.  Make sure you are using [relative paths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/saving-project-with-data-source-path-as-relative-in-qgis).  Zip the directory and share.  The recipient can unzip the project and view the data and see the same things you see.

Comment: Thank you very much GBG.